# How to generate traffic to test a bounce management tool?

Tags: email, smtp, email-bounces

What tools are available to generate bounce messages in order to test a bounce management tool?  We want to test invalid addresses but we will like to test other error status codes.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want an SMTP server that generates such errors in a reliable fashion.

Lots of open-source SMTP servers exist and are available for modification. One option is [Apache James](http://james.apache.org/), a modular open-source Java SMTP server.

A much more trivial test server could simply open port 25 for receiving mails, and deliver canned errors depending on configuration (or incoming email).